# Memory management issues - either "abort", "bus", or "segmentation fault" errors with no explanation

Tags: c

I'm trying to rewrite my python code in C as my analysis requires the analysis of 2,000 files with 1,000,000 x 6 data points. Such file requirements make the analysis in Python awfully slow, so I've been attempting to rewrite it in C. The analysis is performing a Windowed Fast Fourier Transform which I believe would be faster in C, but every attempt to run this gives one of 3 errors: abort", "bus", or "segmentation fault"

Here's the main code structure with comments in vital spots:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

// constants setting up the array size
const int bins=30;
const int pno=1000000; 
const int intv=2000;

// Simple function to assign bin number to each particle in a file
int sort(double x)
{
    int j=0;
    while (x>r_bin*(j+1))
    {
        j+=1;
    }
    return j;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Defining the arrays that will be saved to separate files
    // I require this due to the complex values in the analysis, 
    // easier to save them separately
    double binned_r[intv][bins];
    memset( binned_r, 0, intv*bins*sizeof(double) );
    double binned_c[intv][bins];
    memset( binned_c, 0, intv*bins*sizeof(double) );

    // Main loop that goes through the 2000 files
    for (int k=0;k<intv;k++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", k);
        double x[3];
        FILE *f1;
        char IC[999];
        sprintf(IC,"NFW_12.30103_12.00000_4.544068_1.00.%06d",k);
        f1 = fopen(IC,"r");    
        
        for (int j=0;j<pno;j++)
        {
            double a,b,c;
            fscanf(f1,"%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", &a,&b,&c);
            x[0]=sqrt(a*a+b*b)/1000.;
            x[1]=atan2(b,a);
            x[2]=c/1000.;
            binned_r[k][sort(x[0])]+=creal(x[2]*cexp(I*3*x[1]));
            binned_c[k][sort(x[0])]+=cimag(x[2]*cexp(I*3*x[1]));
        }
    }


    FILE *fill_r;
    char NAM_r[999];
    sprintf(NAM_r, "test_r.dat");
    fill_r = fopen(NAM_r,"w");   
    FILE *fill_c;
    char NAM_c[999];
    sprintf(NAM_c, "test_c.dat");
    fill_c = fopen(NAM_c,"w");
    for (int k=0;k<intv;k++)
    {       
        for (int l=0;l<bins;l++)
            {
                fprintf(fill_r,"%f\t", binned_r[k][l]);
                fprintf(fill_c,"%f\t", binned_c[k][l]);
            }
        fprintf(fill_r,"\n");
        fprintf(fill_c,"\n");
    }
    fclose(fill_r);
}
```

My main reason for requesting help is because every change to this code does not yield results, so I am stuck in understanding if this is a basic syntax issue or if I'm requesting more memory than my laptop can manage.

Even after removing the section that writes the files, the code either gives an "abort" or "bus" error, otherwise it's "segmentation fault". I also attempted utilising

`ulimit -s 65000`

which appeared to help at first, but then failed the same way.

Edit:

The changes suggested by @Schwern (compiling with -fsanitize=address) resulted in this error, however, I am unsure how interpret it as I've never delved that deep into C

```
=================================================================
==71816==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x00016dd52ba0 at pc 0x0001020af698 bp 0x00016dd50d70 sp 0x00016dd50d68
READ of size 8 at 0x00016dd52ba0 thread T0
    #0 0x1020af694 in main+0x828 (a.out:arm64+0x100003694)
    #1 0x185163f24  (<unknown module>)

Address 0x00016dd52ba0 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 7712 in frame
    #0 0x1020aee78 in main+0xc (a.out:arm64+0x100002e78)

  This frame has 8 object(s):
    [32, 7712) 'binned_r' <== Memory access at offset 7712 overflows this variable
    [7968, 7992) 'x'
    [8032, 9031) 'IC'
    [9168, 9176) 'a'
    [9200, 9208) 'b'
    [9232, 9240) 'c'
    [9264, 9280) 'coerce'
    [9296, 9307) 'NAM_r'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow (a.out:arm64+0x100003694) in main+0x828
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x00016dd52900: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00016dd52980: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00016dd52a00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00016dd52a80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00016dd52b00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x00016dd52b80: 00 00 00 00[f2]f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2
  0x00016dd52c00: f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2
  0x00016dd52c80: f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00
  0x00016dd52d00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00016dd52d80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x00016dd52e00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==71816==ABORTING
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

Comment: Use `-fsanitize=address` when compiling. Begin by confirming the files opened. `const char NAM_c[] = "test_c.dat"` is a much simpler way to initialize a constant string.

Comment: What is `r_bin` on line 19?

Comment: Don't forget to close your files after reading.

Comment: @WeatherVane apologies, I removed a line that explains r_bin for brevity. It's the width of a bin. I'm basically trying to perform a binned statistic. So, r_bin acts as a boundary of a bin and the sort() function returns the bin number at which my variable is less than r_bin*j

Comment: Whitespace is not evil...

Comment: `fscanf(f1, "%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", &a, &b, &c);` should be `fscanf(f1, "%lf %lf %lf", &a,  &b, &c);` Cautions: a) never put trailing whitespace in the formattign string, b) *always* check that `scanf` family functions return the correct value: in this case `3`.

Comment: @WeatherVane even if the file itself has \t whitespaces? Sorry if the question is obvious, I expected the fscanf() to error-out if the format is incorrect.

Comment: @Schwern I've implemented the changes and posted the error from -fsanitize=address in my original post at the bottom. I am unsure what it implies as the error is huge and my knowledge in C is not as deep.

Comment: The `%lf` filters whitespace anyway (not all do). Please see [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string) And you must explicitly check that the input was successful. A bad input does not "error out" but informs the caller, so they can take recovery action (if possible).

Comment: Also `-g` when using `-fsanitize=address`.  The statement "'binned_r' <== Memory access at offset 7712 overflows this variable" tells you everything.  One of the indexes to binned_r is out of range.  You will need to check your limits and the `sort()` function to make sure they are correct.

Comment: So, what value do we use for `r_bin` in case we want to run the program? Is it `intv` or `bins`? Also, is the data file (or a smaller data file) that causes the issue available anywhere? pastebin or github?

Comment: @BradLanam Damn it, I even made sure to increase the bin limits to be beyond the highest particle distance - that was the issue, code completed successfully! I am still unsure if it will actually work when I implement all 2000 files (only testing for 20  files to not make everyone wait).

Comment: @CraigEstey in my case it's `r_bin = 0.5`, with a range of `r_min/r_max=0/30`. By dividing `r_max/r_bin` we get `bins`. I wrote it the way it is at the moment because the range and bin width might change if I'm working on some other files.

Comment: When you go to 2000 files, how large will `binned_r` and `binned_c` get? They're on the stack. linux has a [default] limit of 8MB but windows' limit is [much] less (e.g. 4MB or 1MB). You may need to use `calloc` for those arrays.

Comment: You can answer your own question outlining the solution for people running into similar issues.

Comment: `binned_r[k][sort(x[0])]+=creal(x[2]*cexp(I*3*x[1]));` add check is `sort(x[0])` is not outside bounds

Comment: _Side note:_ C doesn't handle `const int` the same way C++ does as far as using it as an array dimension. IIRC, it would be treated as a VLA (vs. an array of fixed dimensions which would be faster). Try: `enum { bins = 30, pno = 1000000, intv = 2000 };`

Comment: @CraigEstey How fixed size array can be faster - please show the proof. The code will be exactly the same for both.

Comment: @CraigEstey I am unsure as it would be a 2000x30 array of doubles. Realistically I would want to avoid making two separate files, but that would mean creating a 2000x2x30 array which also is my worry, so I avoided it for now.

Comment: For the future -- attach gdb to find out where things are going wrong; or, even better, run valgrind's memcheck tool integrated with gdb to find bugs _before_ the point where they would crash in a "real" program: https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver

Comment: @gulpr The proof? ;-) (which should be obvious): Compile OP's program as original (with `const int`). Then, do it with the enum (e.g. add a `#ifdef ENUM` for convenience). Disassemble both versions. The code is _not_ the same and the `const` version is more cumbersome. You don't have to go any further than to compare `main` and the code before the first `memset` call to see the difference.

Comment: @CraigEstey **Yes the proof**. I do not see any difference https://godbolt.org/z/oGoGffc48

Comment: @CraigEstey also a few instructions more when allocating the space does no make code less efficient. It would matter if the access would be more complicated. But in the code reading from files it does not matter.

Comment: @CraigEstey even this version where compiler cant predict the numbers. https://godbolt.org/z/bMfq9j84n

Comment: @CraigEstey "VLA (vs. an array of fixed dimensions which would be faster)" On the vast majority of systems they are allocated exactly the same as fixed dimension arrays - on the stack. The only slight performance difference is that the program may have to keep track of the VLA size in run-time, whereas in case of static arrays the size is hard-coded. Anyway, this whole discussion is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
binned_r[k][sort(x[0])]+=creal(x[2]*cexp(I*3*x[1]));
```

You do not check if `sort(x[0])` is `>= 0` and `< bins`

To debug your program simply

```
if((int)sort(x[0]) < 0 || (int)sort(x[0]) >= bins) 
{
     /* print your error message and exit the program */
}
binned_r[k][sort(x[0])]+=creal(x[2]*cexp(I*3*x[1]));
```

You will know what data is causing the error